# Create Pnr Passenger Details RQ not working sabre

Tags: sabre, sabredav

Getting Error of PASSENGER TYPE ENTERED VALID ONLY FOR INFANT NAME

i am not able to work with infant its working fine for adult & child but as i associate infant it give me that error

PassengerDetailsRQ method

Comment: Please add the request and response so we can respond base on what you are getting.

Answer (score 0):

When using PassengerType="INF" you also to set flag Infant=true.

Answer (score -1):

Generally in Sabre following passenger type codes are used.

1. Adult - **ADT**
2. Child - **CNN**
3. Infant without seat - **INF**
4. Infant with a seat - **INS**